# reallocation of a Matrix in c

Tags: c, memory-management, matrix, malloc, realloc

Probably this is a very stupid question but I can't see through it, maybe you could help?

My problem is the reallocation of a matrix, adding 1 column and 1 row to it and, then, fill the new elements with `INFINITY'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, size = 3;
    float **mat;

    //Initial allocation
    mat = malloc(size* sizeof(float *));
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mat[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(float));
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            mat[i][j] = 1;
    }

    //Print initial matrix
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%f ", mat[i][j]);
        puts("\n");
    }

    //I'm going to add a row and a column
    void *pointer = realloc(mat, (size+1)*sizeof(float*));
    if(pointer != NULL) {
        mat = pointer;
        mat[size] = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(float));
    }else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: allocation");

    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        mat[i][size] = 0;
        mat[size][i] = 0;
    }

    //Print altered matrix
    for(i=0; i<=size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= size; j++)
            printf("%f ", mat[i][j]);
        puts("\n");
    }

    //Here comes the free
    for (i = 0; i < size+1; i++){
        free(mat[i]);  // <-- Debug says SIGTRAP
    }
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: I noticed that only when i'm debugging it gives that error, not while running normally. My IDE is Clion.

Comment: You are not adding a column to anything. You are adding a row, and making that row one element longer than the other rows (presuming they are of length `size`).

Comment: You have not added the extra column.

Comment: How is `mat` declared?

Comment: Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `float **mat`, @WeatherVane @n.m. how should i add the column?

Comment: If you originally `malloc`ed the memory for every row, iterate each row first, doing `realloc` to obtain the extra column. Then add the extra row.

Comment: Using the name 'size' for the largest index of an object that holds 'size + 1' elements is asking for trouble.  Change the name, or change the usage.

Comment: @Olaf I edited the code and made a MCVE.

Comment: Consider only doing a single allocation per matrix, and using pointer-arithmetic instead of row-pointers. Or carve that one up into row-pointers and values. At most, use two allocations...

Comment: There are no stupid questions OP.

Comment: @EzequielMoreno: I strongly disagree!

Comment: 1) You do not have a matrix (i.e. 2D array). A pointer is not an array. 2) Always check the result of functions which might encounter an error, e.g. `malloc` & friends. 3) It is likely easier to use a 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you originally had a 2x2 array.

```
x x
x x
```

After your calls to realloc and malloc, you've created an object that looks like this:

```
x x
x x
x x x
```

To fix this problem, you need to call realloc on each row as well.

---

A complete solution might look like:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, size = 3;
    float **mat;

    // Initial allocation
    mat = malloc(size * sizeof(float *));
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        mat[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(float));

    // Initial values
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            mat[i][j] = 1;

    // Print initial matrix
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%f ", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    // I'm going to add a row and a column
    mat = realloc(mat, (size+1)*sizeof(float*));
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        mat[i] = realloc(mat[i], (size+1)*sizeof(float));
    mat[size] = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(float));

    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        mat[i][size] = 0;
        mat[size][i] = 0;
    }

    //Print altered matrix
    for(i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= size; j++)
            printf("%f ", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Here comes the free
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        free(mat[i]);
    free(mat);
}
```

Comment: So, deleting `mat[size] = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(float));`, should it be like this?
`for(i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        mat[i] = realloc(mat[i], sizeof(float));
        mat[size][i] = 0;
    }`

Comment: @Aster: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand what i was doing wrong now!